# Unable to use d3-legend plugin

Tags: d3.js

I want to add [d3-legend](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/) plugin in my code. I saved the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/susielu/d3-legend/master/d3-legend.min.js) given on the website and added it in my html file as follows:

```
<script src="~/js/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to run the following line(which is part of my working code, btw)

```
var legendLinear = d3.legend.color()
            .shapeWidth(30)
            .orient('horizontal')
            .scale(linear);
```

the app crashes. When I tried debugging, I notice it says `undefined` on the legend. So somehow `d3.legend` is not initialized.

I also tried adding it using CDN, without success.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.19.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
```

The docs says I should be able to use it directly after adding it. Am I missing something here?

Note: When I do a file search in chrome devtools, I can see the added files(both the .js file and the cdn version, still I am not able to use `d3.legend`)

**Edit: This issue is fixed. I was using wrong version. See the comment below.**

Comment: I was using the d3v4 plugin. It works now after I added the d3v3 version, starting with 1.*, (was going to delete the question but I think it might help others doing the same mistake)